# PHP execution on apache server

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, redhat

I have installed MySQL 5.5.34 , Apache 2.2.15 and PHP 5.5.4 in respective order on my linux Redhat system (2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.x86_64).

When the php script is being run on the web browser, it is being interpreted as html by  apache although its working fine in command line.

I have done the following changes in the **httpd.conf** file:
I have uncommented **LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so** .

The .php index has been defined as follows:

**DirectoryIndex index.html index.php** .

```
<FilesMatch "\.ph(p[2-6]?|tml)$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*\.php)s$ $1 [H=application/x-httpd-php-source]
```

It would be of great help, if anybody could assist me in this.

Comment: what is the extension on your script?

Comment: i have saved all my php scripts as ".php".

Comment: Try this regex `\.php|phtml$` https://regex101.com/r/hVu8fO/1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem is there: `\.ph(p[2-6]?|tml)$`, it's doesn't match the *.php file names.
Try to rename any php file to .php3 and try to acces directly from browser. Or just change the regexp to `\.php$`

Comment: The result is still same.